# Equivalent condition of vanishing of $l$-adic Tate module

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, finite-groups, modules

Let A be an abelian group and $T_{l}(A) = \varprojlim_{n} A[l^{n}]$ be the $l$-adic Tate module of an abelian group for a prime $l$. We denote $A \lbrace l \rbrace = \lbrace x \in A  :  l^{n}x = 0  \hspace{1mm} for \hspace{1mm} some \hspace{1mm} n \in \mathbb{N} \rbrace $. I would like to know some of the equivalent conditions of vanishing of the group $T_{l}(A)$.

For example, I know one of sufficient conditions. If the subgroup $A \lbrace l \rbrace$ is finite or more generally has finite exponent.  Then $T_{l}(A) = 0.$

For simplicity, we can ask if $A$ is an $l$-torsion group. Is it true that $T_{l}(A) = 0$ implies that $A$ is of finite exponent. If not, what is an example or what be one of the sufficient condition on $A$ for this vanishing?

Comment: $A=\bigoplus_n \Bbb{Z}/l^n\Bbb{Z}$ is an $l$-group with infinite exponent and trivial $T_l(A)$

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem obvious to see if $T_l(A)$ will be trivial.

For example let $G=\bigoplus_{n\ge 1} \Bbb{Z}/l^n\Bbb{Z}$,

$e_n$ the element of $G$ with $0$ everywhere except a $1$ in $n$-th position,

$H$ the subgroup generated by all the $e_1-l^{n-1}e_n$,

and $A=G/H$. It is an $l$-group, with infinite exponent, furthermore $$\bigcap_{n\ge 1} l^n A$$ isn't trivial (it contains $e_1$). But $T_l(A)$ is trivial.

Comment: Can you provide little bit hint how one show $T_{l}(A) = 0$?

Comment: An element of $T_l(A)$ is a sequence $(a_n)$ such that $la_n=a_{n-1}$. So all the $a_n$ are $l^\infty$ divisible. Here only $A[p] = \langle e_1\rangle$ is $l^\infty$ divisible.